# selected statement in joining table

Tags: sql, sql-server

`movie`:

```
   id ,title,yr,director,budget,gross
```

`actor`:

```
   id,name
```

`casting`:

```
   movieid,actorid,ord
```

I have a question on this I has been asking to (List the films together with the leading star for all 1962 films.)  [Note: the ord field of casting gives the position of the actor. If ord=1 then this actor is in the starring role]

My answer was this:

```
select 
    title, name 
from 
    movie 
join 
    casting on movie.id = casting.movieid
join 
    actor on actor.id = casting.actorid
where 
    yr = 1962 and movie.id = casting.movieid and actor.id = casting.actorid and casting.ord = 1  
group by 
    title
```

But what my problem was I can get close to the answer, I have the problem at the ord part because some of the casting do not have 1 for the actor that just showing two, so it will not display on the output.

How could I make it select ord =1 or ord =2 (but not both)(and 1 have higher priority)

Hope anyone can help me this.

Comment: As a side note, you have repeated your join-conditions in your `where` clause, that is not necessary.

Comment: @oerkelens i was actually trying to joining this 3 table together. this is not the ways ?

Comment: your join is fine, but you do not need the same conditions in your where clause again. (That was only done with _implicit_ joins where one would use _no_ join conditions. Using explicit joins the way you did is better.)

Answer (score 0):

Use CROSS APPLY (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with a subquery which is ordered by the 'ord' column and has a TOP(1) clause.

```
SELECT
    M.title
    , CA.name 
FROM
    movie AS M
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            actor.name
        FROM
            casting C
            INNER JOIN actor A
                ON C.actorid = A.id
        WHERE
            M.id = C.movieid
        ORDER BY
            ord
        ASC
) AS CA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select title,coalesce (c.name,c21.name) as actorname from movie m 
left join (select * from casting where ord=1) c on m.id= c.movieid
left join (select * from casting where ord=2) c1 on c.movieid = c1.movieid 
left join actor a on a.id= c.actorid
where yr=1962
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will output your expected result

```
   Select title,name
    From Movie M
       Cross Apply (Select  top 1 movieid,actorid,ord from  Casting Order By ord) as Cast
    Inner join Actor A On A.id = Cast. actorid
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 answers:

```
SELECT movie.title, (select actor.name from actor where actor.id = casting.actorid)
FROM movie
JOIN casting
ON movie.id =casting.movieid
WHERE movie.yr = 1962 and casting.ord = 1
```

But then I realized that you can chain joins:

```
SELECT movie.title, actor.name
FROM movie
JOIN casting ON movie.id=casting.movieid
JOIN actor ON casting.actorid = actor.id
WHERE movie.yr = 1962 and casting.ord = 1
```

The second one is clearly much simpler. (There's no need to nest a `SELECT` statement).

To have it select either or, do `... and (casting.ord = 1 xor casting.ord = 2)`. 
To order it by 1, try something like `Order by casting.ord in (1,2)`. (I haven't tested that.